# MPAndroidChart - Clicking on an entry on the graph highlights the wrong entry. Is there a solution without rewriting the lib locally?

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

I created a simple linechart with MPAndroidChart and when I try to click on a point, MPAndroidChart calls:

```
public Entry getEntryForHighlight(Highlight highlight) {
        if (highlight.getDataSetIndex() >= mDataSets.size())
            return null;
        else {
            return mDataSets.get(highlight.getDataSetIndex()).getEntryForXValue(highlight.getX(), highlight.getY());
        }
    }



T getEntryForXValue(float xValue, float closestToY);
```

I have 3 entries [x;y] -> **[17;98.1] [17;101.3] [17;103.8]**

If I click on the one with **Y=103.8**, the code above from the library returns the entry with **Y=101.3**

The **highlight.getY()** returns **103.8** correctly though, and I don't understand how can **101.3** be closer to **103.8** than **103.8** itself?

If I click on the entry with **Y=101.3** it works as intended, same for **Y=98.1**

Comment: Have you found out the reason?

Comment: @DinhQuangTuan Sorry, I don't have access to the source code anymore, but as far as I know it was a bug somewhere else when adding the values.